# VSTS execute automated tests after Octopus Deploy finishes a deployment

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, octopus-deploy

I recently discovered Selenium and am using it in test protects in Visual Studio for testing ASP.Net web projects in the same solution.  We have VSTS build definitions set up for our web projects that deploy to Azure using Octopus Deploy.  Is there any way I can configure the same VSTS build defs to somehow wait a specified period of time until the Octopus Deploy completes,  and then run the unit tests in the solution being built and deployed?

Comment: If the Octopus Deploy tasks don't already give you the option, then you'll have to write your own set of scripts. I assume that Octopus has some sort of API you can query for status. Just hard-coding a delay is wasteful at worst and ineffective at best. If you've adopted Octopus for your deployment automation, you could also add testing into your Octopus deployment pipeline.

Comment: Could you share your build definition? Did you try to add a [VSTest task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) after Octopus Deploy task, and select `Only when all previous tasks have succeeded` in `Run this task` option?

Comment: The Octopus deploy task may complete but complete only means the package was copied to Octopus, it is actually deployed manually from Octopus after that.  I guess I'm just asking if you can manually execute a UI test from vsts test that's included in a web project

Comment: @PatrickGoode You could check this blog: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1386/automated-tests-test-hub-vsts, does it what you want?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT This looks pretty cool, thanks.  It looks like its for on premises TFS though?  I did find this however....  https://nugridium.azurewebsites.net/documentation/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1